# How to cancel an update() in a Svelte store?

Tags: javascript, svelte

Svelte stores can be updated via the `store.update()` method.

```js
store.update((currentValue) => {
  return currentValue + 1;
});
```

Is it possible to cancel an update in the update function itself so that the subscribers to the store are not triggered?

For example, we may way want to introduce some logic to decide whether to trigger and update to the subscribers or not.

```js
store.update((currentValue) => {
  // this doesn't work because it sets the value of the store to undefined
  if (currentValue >= 10) return;
  return currentValue + 1;
});
```

A solution is to decide beforehand if the store should be updated or not, but in more advanced use cases this can become cumbersome and even lead to duplication of code.

```js
if (get(store) < 10) {
  store.update((currentValue) => {
    return currentValue + 1;
  });
}
```

Is there any other solution to this issue?

Comment: Your second code snippet would work if you just return `currentValue` from the if statement: `if (currentValue >= 10) return currentValue;`

Comment: @JHeth no because that would still trigger the update regardless of the returned value.

Comment: It makes a difference if the value is a primitive https://svelte.dev/repl/f2a0f56a630f4e0ca7cc8812fac939fd?version=3.55.1

Comment: @Corrl huh interesting. Unfortunately, I need it for non primitive values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either write your own store that implements that logic or use a separate function to update stores. `update` is just a utility function anyway which does not need to exist on stores to function.

E.g. the latter approach:

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

export class Cancel extends Error {}

export const cancel = () => { throw new Cancel() };

export function update(store, callback) {
    const value = get(store);
    try {
        const newValue = callback(value);
        store.set(newValue);
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof Cancel)
            return;
        
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
update(store, value => {
    if (value == 10)
        cancel();
    
    return value + 1;
})
```

(The `cancel` function could also be passed to the callback as another argument.)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1b1c541e285f4c70bf183c2438019000?version=3.55.1)